# How to assign C# variable to asp element using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, variables

I want to assign a csharp variable to the element of asp page using javascript. It seems the assignement is not working in my code.

Here it is:

```
document.getElementById('lbAccessories').innerHTML = '<%#SelectLabel%>';
```

In my asp code i use:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAccessories" runat="server" />'
```

I can't assign the value directly to the linkbutton using `Text='<%#SelectLabel%>'` because i want to make it more intelligent.

Does anyone knows how to do with that?

Thanks

**Edit:**

Here is my code, I've tried to use `<%=lbAccessories.clientId%>`, but it generates an error : lbAccessories does not exist in the context.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function function(Ref) {
        if ('<%=TextBoxClientID%>' == 'txtLink') 
        {
            document.getElementById('lbAccessories').innerHTML = '<%#SelectLabel%>';
        }
        else if ('<%=TextBoxClientID%>' == 'btnSearch') {
            document.getElementById('lbAccessories').innerHTML = '<%#ViewDetail%>';
        }
    }

</script>
```

**Edit:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="pic">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAccessories" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%#string.Format("passAccessory(\"{0}\");", Eval("Ref"))%>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Edit:

Thanks so much for everyone who had posted the suggestions.

I have changed the javascript code to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function passAccessory(accessoryRef) {

        if ('<%=TextBoxClientID%>' == 'txtLink') {
            document.getElementById('<%= gvAccessories.FindControl("lbAccessories").ClientID %>').innerHTML = '<%#SelectLabel%>';
        }
        else if ('<%=TextBoxClientID%>' == 'btnSearch') {
            document.getElementById('<%= gvAccessories.FindControl("lbAccessories").ClientID %>').innerHTML = '<%#ViewDetail%>';
        }
    }
</script>
```

in `*.aspx.cs` file, i have added: `protected LinkButton lbAccessories { get; set; }`

It throws an exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Anyone have ideas? Thanks so much

**Edit:**

Finally, we did it with csharp code. It's more flexable and manageable. My colleague helped me. Thank you all for your help!!!

Comment: The javascript is executing before the link button has been added to the DOM

Comment: You appear to be wanting to set the text for the `LinkButton` when you click on it, but the button will POST back to the server when clicked. Is this what you want?

Comment: This is a user control. Different pages include the user control. But the view is a little different when different pages are loaded. So i want to use javascript to judge different conditions and to show different content in the `LinkButton` which is located in a gridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the output HTML whether an anchor's ID is actually what you are looking for. In any case you should rather use `<%= lbAccessories.ClientID %>` than refering to server ID from client script.

If you for some reason don't want to (or cannot) use `<%= lbAccessories.ClientID %>` then check following article about jQuery plugin which allows you to get DOM element by server ID:

http://radek-stromsky.blogspot.com/2010/11/aspnet-how-to-get-client-id-with-jquery.html

**EDIT:**

I made several changes in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function passAccessory(Ref) {
        if ('<%= TextBoxClientID %>' == 'txtLink') 
        {
            document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.FindControl("lbAccessories").ClientID %>').innerHTML = '<%# SelectLabel %>';
        }
        else if ('<%= TextBoxClientID %>' == 'btnSearch') {
            document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.FindControl("lbAccessories").ClientID %>').innerHTML = '<%#ViewDetail%>';
        }
    }
</script>

 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAccessories" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%#string.Format("passAccessory(\"{0}\");", Eval("Ref"))%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

**EDIT: EDIT:**

I fixed the code above. Now there is `GridView1.FindControl("lbAccessories")`

Comment: Why it always generate the error: `CS0103: The name 'lbAccessories' does not exist in the current context`?  I think if i use lbAccessories like your example, i have declare it in the code behind.

Comment: Yes that's what you need to do.

Comment: If you define control with explicit ID, Visual Studio should generate member with such name in *.aspx.designer.cs file. Search that file and see if "lbAccessories" is defined there.

Comment: This problem can be cause by having this block of code inside one of the FormView's Templates. In such situation, you cannot simply access this control via ID.

Comment: I just found that lbAccessories doesn't exist in the file *.aspx.designer.cs, and i have put the LinkButton in a gridview's template. I have pasted the code in the post. Do you know how to correct it?

Comment: Then to access your LinkButton, you must use FindControl method like this: GridView1.FindControl("lbAccessories")

Comment: I declares a `protected LinkButton lbAccessories { get; set; }` in the file *.aspx.cs. When the code try to find lbAccessories, it produces `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: You really have to user FindControl method of the GridView to access that particular control. So you can declare your property like this:

protected LinkButton lbAccessories
{
  get
  {
    return GridView1.FindControl("lbAccessories") as LinkButton;
  }
}

Just change "GridView1" to whatever your name of GridView is.

Comment: It produces the same compilation error. I saw someone's code, Do i need to specify Row in it? I'm really confused.

Comment: No, you're not. My bad, I look through some details in your post. It is really like you noted. You have to access specific row of the GridView. So finally, correct code would be: gvAccessories.Rows[0].FindControl("lbAccessories");

Comment: Of course, you have to say what row exactly you want to access, because every row contains this control.

Comment: Because the LinkButton is contained in a gridview, I want the LinkButton can get each value in each row. And in my code, though i have specified the row as `gvAccessories.Rows[0].FindControl("lbAccessories").ClientID`, it will generate `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `SelectLabel` is a public or protected string member or property of your ASP.NET Page, you should be able to render the string using:

```
document.getElementById('<%= lbAccessories.ClientID %>').innerHTML = '<%= SelectLabel%>';
```

Is there a reason why the "intelligence" you require can't be server-side? If you are setting SelectLabel using C#, you should be able to dynamically set `lbAccessories.Text = SelectLabel;` too.

Comment: It assigns the value to the element.innerHTML, but it does't show in the linkbutton. Do you know why?

Comment: See my update, if you must use javascript, you need to output the ClientId of the LinkButton in the javascript.

Comment: I want to make a if judgement using javascript, the element's value changes depending on the conditions.

Comment: Move your javascript to the end of the page.

Comment: I have put it at the end of the page, the same error: `CS0103: The name does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Does it help if you add a protected member to your code behind: `protected LinkButton lbAccessories;`

Comment: It produces an error : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' It seems what i did in aspx page is not recognized in the javascript code, because it need me to create an instance of the LinkButton. Why javascript doesn't know the LinkButton of the aspx page?

Answer (score 1):

add a hiddenfield with id="hid1" and set its value to the selectlabelvalue, then:

> ```
> document.getElementById('lbAccessories').innerHTML
> ```
>
> = document.getElementById('hid1').innerHTML;

JQuery:

```
$('#lbAccessories).html($('#hid1').html());
```

Comment: if you have a master page or working inside a user control, note that the id will change, you should use UniqueID in client script

Answer (score 1):

lbAccessories is a Server side control. When the server emits HTML for it, it assigns a unique ClientId to the control. In the JavaScript you have to access it via it's ClientId like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%=lbAccessories.ClientId%>').innerHTML = '<%#SelectLabel%>';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried but it generate an error: `CS0103: The name 'lbAccessories' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: The ClientId should be ClientID instead. Where in the aspx page is your JavaScript located?

Comment: It's located in the same page; and it generates the same error